# Async js files load in Rails (with JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asynchronous

Does anyone tried to play with async: true for js includes in Rails? I mean it works great but just if you are not using jQuery. If you do, then you could face some strange effects like "$" is not defined and etc. There is plenty of articles how to avoid that, but all of them seems to be done with no Rails in mind. For example, this one: http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader

Seems like I have to move jQuery from applicaction.js - means out from being putted into one big file with other JS I have.

Just wonder is there some "rails-way" of loading js asynchronously since Google is strongly recommended to do that (it is affected a page load speed a lot, and as a result - your Page Rank)?

Comment: awesome question, I will try to find someone to answer it cuz I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser issue, not a Rails issue. In short, you can't do this on most browsers. This will cause a dependency error, which is what the error points to. One solution is to add the dependency in a file with all the dependent code.
However, this problem has been solved in ES6, using JavaScript imports. There is a guide on how to implement these imports in another answer here. See [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/950087) for that info.